# Converting nested JSON response to a CSV table

Tags: json, api, postman, export-to-csv, file-conversion

I am testing APIs on a locally run service using Postman. I am getting a large nested response as JSON. But I am required to produce a CSV file with the data in tables. i.e., keys as column names and the values as separate rows into the tables

An offline solution for needed, for privacy and confidentiality reasons.

---

#### First I came across this solution: [postman saveResponseToFile template](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/3407886/RWgp1fB5?version=latest#f0f97744-0413-4bcf-b4e4-7c85939c5a7f)

A template of postman that sends the requests to a node server running locally which in turn saves the JSON to a CSV.

But all this does is save each line into a separate cell horizontally across the CSV. Not of much use for readability.

---

#### Desired Output

The needed table is something like what this online tool does:

[ConvertCSV](http://convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm)

This takes the keys as column names and creates new rows for each nested data.

---

Is there a OSS script that can accomplish this. Sorry if this is a duplicate. I haven't found a proper one after trying more similar scripts similar to the first.